# Controlling state of a widget from another widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I'm using the example in this link:
https://medium.com/@jb.padamchopra/implementing-a-bottom-app-bar-with-floating-action-button-flutter-463560e1324
[Widget from the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fIqz.png)

The floating action button animation is controlled by a bool clickedCenterFAB
In my code the Widgets inside the animated container are defined in a class and I want, after the user writes a text and presses the button, the animated container to collapse, so logically I want to call setState and assign clickedCenterFAB = false.
I'm new to flutter and I tried calling setState inside the uploadPage widget and try to change clickedCenterFAB but it didn't work. Any idea how to do it guys? thanks for the help in advance.
[My widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLVYm.jpg)

```
AnimatedContainer(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              //if clickedCentreFAB == true, the first parameter is used. If it's false, the second.
              height: clickedCentreFAB
                  ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
                  : 10.0,
              width: clickedCentreFAB
                  ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
                  : 10.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.circular(clickedCentreFAB ? 0.0 : 300.0),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: clickedCentreFAB ? UploadPage() : null)
```

EDIT: After following with Michael's solution and keeping up with the comments, this is where I got

```
class UploadPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function collapseContainer;
  UploadPage(this.collapseContainer);
  @override
  _UploadPageState createState() => 
_UploadPageState(collapseContainer);
}

class _UploadPageState extends State<UploadPage> {
  final Function collapseContainer;
  _UploadPageState(this.collapseContainer);
...
...
CustomButton(
              () {
                if (_controller.text.trim().isNotEmpty) {
                  DatabaseServices().uploadPost(
                      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid,
                      _controller.text,
                      !_isChecked);
                  collapseContainer;
                }
              },
              'Post',
              Colors.white,
            ),
```

CustomButton obviously is a widget class that i created to avoid redundency and in the params in a Function which I'm passing here

Comment: Use Statemanagement libraries like `flutter_bloc`, `provider`,`getX`, `mobX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't call setState directly from UploadPage is because setState is a class method, so it's always only associated with the state of the immediately enclosing class instance. If you want to change the state of a Widget that's higher up in the Widget tree, the standard method is to pass a callback to the child component.

In your case, you might add a new property to your UploadPage widget - something like, onButtonPressed:

```
class UploadPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onButtonPressed;
  UploadPage({required this.onButtonPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return YourWidget(
      // ...
      child: RaisedButton(onPressed: onButtonPressed),
      // ...
    );
  }
}
```

Then:

```
AnimatedContainer(
  // ...
  child: clickedCentreFAB 
           ? UploadPage(
             onButtonPressed: () {
               setState(() { return clickedCentreFAB = false; });
             },
           ) 
           : null,
  )
)
```

As an aside, at a certain point, the state of your app may be complex enough to warrant solutions like `bloc`, `redux`, etc - However, for this particular scenario those might be overkill.

If you find yourself having to pass callbacks and properties through several levels of the widget tree, then `provider` can be immensely helpful.

If the mapping between actions, states, and views becomes very complex, then `bloc` or `redux` can help to impose structure onto your project and make it easier to reason about, though you will often need to write more code to get the same tasks done.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply! This works fine, but in my button's onPressed I'm doin a whole bunch of stuff, I'm checking if the editTextField is empty and if it's not I'm calling a Firebase method to upload the text to Firestore. And with the callback being a function it doesn't work with all the other code because they're already wrapped in a function. So if i use the callback alone it works but otherwise not. I tried using VoidCallBack instead of function and MethodCall but it also did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Np! If I understand correctly, you should still be able to pass in a callback - perhaps call it "onDone" instead, and then just call it after the other work is done. Something like `onPressed: () async { await doStuff(); onDone(); },`. Any reason that wouldn't work?

Comment: I tried that now, it didn't work :( The text is being uploaded to firestore correctly but everything after that in that function is not working.

Comment: Ah, that's too bad - Would you mind sharing the relevant code from your UploadPage, and how UploadPage is constructed from the parent widget?

Comment: No not at all! Give me a few hours I'm currently not near my setup

Comment: Updated my question with the code you requested, If I remove everything including (){} in the CustomButton params and only include the callback it would work as i said before but i can't do anything else then.

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail! It might only be a typo in the above code, but I noticed the collapseContainer function isn't actually called - If you change `collapseContainer;` to `collapseContainer();` then does it work?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming DatabaseServices.uploadPost is an asynchronous function - You might need to `await` that function call so that the callback isn't called until after the upload is completed

Comment: IT WORKEEEDDDD!!!! Thanks a lot brother you've been an immense help! I really appreciated. You learn something new everyday

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it!